# Access windowController's button From subView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my cocoa OS X application, I have a **WindowController** with a xib file, and ***Two***  **ViewControllers** with xib files, I have added a Custom View in the WindowController, Where I am swapping those two Sub Views by removing and adding those Views when clicked in continue or next button.

```
[[theViewController view] removeFromSuperview];
self.theViewController = [[WelcomeInstallViewController alloc] initWithNibName:newView bundle:nil];
[innerInstallerView addSubview:[theViewController view]];
[[theViewController view] setFrame:[innerInstallerView bounds]];
```

Now In one of those views i have a button which needs to disable the continue button in the WindowController.I have looked into **NSNotificationCenter**, this is my first mac,cocoa, objective c app. should i use NSNotificationCenter? i am confused, and didn't understand properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to skin the cat..

The simplest approach would consist of adding an outlet to your `NSWindowController` and link the button to that outlet in Interface Builder, then handle the button enablement on whatever conditions you require.

Notifications are one good way of loosely coupling application components, e.g. in case the window controller doesn't initiate the state change that would trigger the button to disable/enable itself.

Other possibilities include [NSUserInterfaceValidations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSUserInterfaceValidations_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), a dedicated mechanism (protocol) in Cocoa to..

*allow the target of a user interface element such as a menu item or a toolbar item to decide whether or not the user interface element should be enabled.*

Comment: but action (a button triggred) must come from one of the sub views, then it will disable the button in the windowController.

Answer (score 0):

Given a similar design requirement (multiple loadable XIBs), I have used the `NSViewController` paradigm to allow logic to be attached to the sub-views that I load into the main view.   In this case, I would create an `NSViewController` subclass which has a bool property (let's call it `canContinue`), which I would bind from the main view's button to owner's `subview.canContinue`.

If you do this, the main view will have to load the view controller (which will take care of loading the XIB) when you bring in each of the individual subviews, and then make sure to assign the `subview` property in the owner to point to the `NSViewController` that you load.